# End the game after 5 seconds of inactivity

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm new to Phaser.io so I do apologize if this post isn't well.

How to end the game after 5 seconds of inactivity ? I've made something but I think it is really really bad for performance.
Each time the update function is called I check if the user didn't pushed "up, left, right, down" and after I check if we have exceed the time by doing (currentTime - beginningTime > 5000).
This code has 2 problems I'm trying to fire : 
- The performance is really bad because it is not necessary too check every time we call the update function
- In my condition I want to check that "no key has been pushed" and for now I just check if the user didn't pushed "up", "left", "right" or "down"

How to do that ?
Sorry for my english

```
var timeBeginning = new Date().getTime();

function update() {
    // input to move the ship
    if (cursors.up.isDown) {
        game.physics.arcade.accelerationFromRotation(ship.rotation, 200, ship.body.acceleration);
    } else {
        // stopper the acceleration 
        ship.body.acceleration.set(0);
    }

    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        ship.body.angularVelocity = -300;
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        ship.body.angularVelocity = 300;
    } else {
        // stop the rotation
        ship.body.angularVelocity = 0;
    }

    if (!cursors.up.isDown && !cursors.left.isDown && !cursors.right.isDown && !cursors.down.isDown) {
        if (new Date().getTime() - timeBeginning > 5000) {
            end();
        }
    } else {
        timeBeginning = new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add global keyboard event listener by **game.input.keyboard.addCallbacks**

```js
var timeBeginning = Date.now();

function create(){
    function updateTime(){
        timeBeginning = Date.now();
    }
    game.input.keyboard.addCallbacks(game, updateTime, updateTime);
}

function update() {
    //your code

    if (Date.now() - timeBeginning > 5000) {
        end();
    }
}
```